# Сколько основ в придаточном предложении?

Tags: синтаксис

Здравствуйте, вчера вышел спор с филологом по поводу количества придаточных предложений.

> ***Я думаю,что какой бы любовь ни была  -  большой  или  страстной, не стоит из-за нее, как Желтков из-за своей любви к Вере Николаевне, кончать жизнь самоубийством.***

***Вопрос: какой бы любовь ни была  -  большой  или  страстной  - это придаточное?*** Филолог утверждает, что придаточное 1, не стоит из-за нее, как Желтков из-за своей любви к Вере Николаевне - придаточное -2-ое,  кончать жизнь самоубийством - придаточное 3-ие.  Я считаю, что это одно придаточное - изъяснительное.  Иначе нужна запятая после ''что''.

С другой стороны, часть "какой бы любовь ни была  -  большой  или  страстной''  - нельзя перенести без ущерба смысла.

Есть ли какие-нибудь мнения?

Comment: Пришел ответ от Граммы. Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имеем СПП (главное + первое придаточное):

***Я думаю, что  не стоит из-за нее [т. е. любви] кончать жизнь самоубийством.***

Плюс придаточное уступительное -- второе придаточное:

***"какой бы любовь ни была - большой или страстной".***

(Первое придаточное является главным предложением для второго. См.: *Какой бы любовь ни была - большой или страстной, не стоит из-за нее кончать жизнь самоубийством*.)

Плюс сравнительный оборот:
***"как Желтков из-за своей любви к Вере Николаевне".***

==================

Итого: главное + два придаточных с последовательным подчинением + сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Комментарий там закончились, пишу здесь. Слава, почему вы не можете изъять придаточное? Вполне можно переставить придаточное. А в моем примере, да вы правы: остается местоимение ее. Именно это местоимение говорит о том, что ранее речь шла о чем-то, что нет в данном предложении. Вот поэтому и не уверен по поводу запятой. Мне нужно правило, на которое я могу сослаться.

Comment: Почему я не могу изъять придаточное? Потому что в предложении при этом изъятии будет не хватать каких-то слов. К примеру, слова "затем". См.  «Собака сначала всё время бежала впереди охотника, но [затем]  шаги её замедлились и стали крадущимися».

===

А по поводу правила -- см. Розенталя:

При "встрече" двух подчинительных союзов (или подчинительного союза и союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, если изъятие второй придаточной части не требует перестройки главной части...

Comment: Но переставить можете.

Comment: А Вы в своём предложении изъять можете.

===

P.S.

А вот этим Вы меня здорово рассмешили:

Филолог утверждает, что...  

не стоит из-за нее, как Желтков из-за своей любви к Вере Николаевне - придаточное -2-ое, 

кончать жизнь самоубийством - придаточное 3-ие.

Comment: Нет, не могу. Я уже сказал, из-за местоимения ''ее'' не могу. Правило, которое вы приводите,  я знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Данное предложение является сложным синтаксическим целым.

Старшая конструкция - это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, при этом изъяснительную часть составляет второе СПП с придаточным уступки.

Это цельная конструкция, поэтому нет запятой, поэтому перестановка главной и придаточной части невозможна.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Подобные предложения интересны следующим: у них семантика, грамматика и интонация, в соответствии с которыми ставятся знаки препинания, не составляют единое целое.

ГРАММАТИКА такова: старшей конструкцией является СПП с изъяснительной частью, которая, в свою очередь, является СПП со значением уступки. Мы имеем три предикативные основы, последовательное подчинение тоже имеет место. Но вот семантика не совпадает полностью с грамматикой, а интонация и знаки препинания учитывают это.

В действительности, смысл сообщения - это содержание уступительной части предложения, в то время как главную часть, стоящую в начале предложения, вообще можно заменить вводным словом ("по моему мнению", "скорее всего").

В результате всё сложное предложение делится паузой и запятой на две (а не на три) части, при этом первое предложение (главное) составляет единое целое со вторым предложением (придаточным уступительным).

И О ПЕРЕСТАНОВКЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЙ

Перестановка - это формальный прием, но при этом следует учитывать, что при перестановке в предложении происходят семантические изменения: связь из чисто подчинительной (схема: главное-придаточное) становится взаимообусловленной (схема: придаточное-главное), и всё это находит отражение в языке.

Comment: А изъять придаточное уступительное тоже не получится?

Comment: Слава, в том и дело, что не получится. Предложение ''Я думаю,что не стоит из-за нее, как Желтков из-за своей любви к Вере Николаевне, кончать жизнь самоубийством'' - не имеет законченного смысла.

Comment: Получается, что какая бы ни была - какая -  союзное слово? И нужна ли запятая?

Comment: С одной стороны, нет второй части двойного союза, но запятую не могу вставить.Паузу не чувствую.

Comment: А в предложении "Он сказал, что если будет свободен, вечером придёт ко мне" паузу после "что" чувствуете?

===

А по поводу законченного смысла... Вас смущает, что вместо слова "любви" в предложении после изъятия придаточного останется местоимение "неё"? А контекст-то на что?

===

"Какая бы ни" -- да, мест. в знач. сз. сл.

Comment: да, пауза есть. К тому же запятая нужна.

Comment: Так вы запятую поставите или нет?

Comment: Я бы не ставил, но... 

===

«Собака сначала всё время бежала впереди охотника, но (1) как только она почувствовала дичь, шаги её замедлились и стали крадущимися».

===

Я и в этом предложении паузы не чувствую,  и придаточное "как только она почувствовала дичь" не сумел бы изъять, и запятую после "но" не ставил бы, но…

См.

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_473839